# Boost find_first how does it work? / Define a range

Tags: c++, arrays, string, boost, char

I have a buffer ( e.g. `char buffer[1024]` ) which gets filled with some data. Now I want to search for a substring in this buffer. Since it should be a case insenstive search I am using `boost::algorithm::ifind_first`.

So I  call the function like this:

```
boost::iterator_range<char*> buf_iterator;
buf_iterator = boost::algorithm::ifind_first(buffer ,"substring");
```

This actually works fine. But my concern is the following:

I pass the function just a `char pointer`, so `ifind_first` should have no idea where my buffer ends, but it still works tho.

Now my first idea was that the function searches until a string-termination  character. But in the [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_first.html) the function is defined like this:

```
template<typename Range1T, typename Range2T> 
  iterator_range< typename range_iterator< Range1T >::type > 
  find_first(Range1T & Input, const Range2T & Search);
```

Since it works with template parameters I actually doubt that it is working with null termination?

So my question is how does `ifind_first` know where to stop? 
Or to be more precise, how can I give it a range? As already mentioned it works just fine with a `char*` but I'm not quite sure if I wasn't just lucky - I mean in the worst case the function is called and doesn't know where to stop and goes into undefined memory...

**Edit:**

Now in an answer there was mentioned that it depends on the type I pass to the function. Now this would mean if I work with a `char` buffer I have to always make sure it`s 0-terminated...?

Comment: If the docs state the method it's very well hidden!

Comment: Please do not sign your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses a technique where the length of an array is a template argument, ie:

```
template< typename T, size_t L >
void foo( T (&arr)[L] )
{
}
```

As a string literal has known length L can be deduced, such as foo( "test" ) being foo< char, 5 >(). I bet there's an overload for const char* where it's assumed that the argument is a c-string, where strlen() can be used to determine the length.

**EDIT: Better explanation demonstration how ifind_first will fail, and why it won't if you're careful**

What decides whether ifind_first will fail or not in this case is whether either subject or search degenerates into a char*. In this case you've passed a string literal as the search directly, ifind_first will try and guess will conclude that it's const char[ 10 ] ( length of "substring" + 1 for NULL terminator ). However, for the search it does not matter, because even if it degenerates to const char* ifind_first will guess that it's a NULL terminated c string, and a string literal is a NULL terminated c string an therefor works dandy.

In this case you're really asking for char buffer[1024], in your case it does not degenerate to char*. But if instead you would've had lets say char* buffer = new char[1024]; the type of buffer is char* and it's not guaranteed to be NULL terminated. In this case ifind_first will fail in mysterious ways depending on what's after the area you've filled.

So, to conclude, as the type of buffer is char[1024] in your case it will not touch memory past the end of buffer, BUT, it will also not care about whether there's a NULL terminator in there ( it doesn't look for it, as you've passed it a char[1024] it knows the length at compile time ). So if lets say you fill buffer with 12 characters followed by NULL it will still search the whole buffer.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it seems to be working with a non-null terminated `char` buffer, where `strlen()` won't help.

Comment: So that means for example: If I have a buffer with 1024 Bytes I should initialize my buffer with `char buffer[1025] = {0}` so I make sure it is **always** null terminated ( even when I receive exactly 1024 bytes )... ?

Comment: @nabulke: No, char buffer[1024] is fixed size, it's not char* ( although it can degenerate into char* if you're not careful ). Try buf_iterator = boost::algorithm::ifind_first((char*)buffer ,"substring");

Comment: +1: your answer seems informed. Did you analyzed the source or could you add a link to some relevant doc? I failed to find the info in boost docs (either string_algo or range).

Comment: I took a look at the source, it uses boost::as_literal ( check boost/range/detail/as_literal.hpp ). It then goes to str_begin / str_end -> range_begin / range_end . range_begin is straightforward, but range_end goes through a couple of layers of indirection to finally end up at range/detail/implementation_help.hpp where the above mentioned technique kicks in at line 63 / 69.